# Formulario php no envia datos a base de datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es que no se registran los datos a la base de datos, Nose si es un error de código o algo haci...

ESTE ES MI FORMULARIO...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES MI CÓDIGO PARA ENVIAR A LA BASE DE DATOS (CON LA CONEXIÓN)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO DE CONEXION A BDD:

```html
<?php

$servidor ="localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contraseña = "";
$base = "base";

$enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $base);

if(!$enlace){

echo "no funciona mysql";

}


?>
```

CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO HTML:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<center><h1>Titulo Archivo:</h1><input required class="titulo" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo del archivo...">
<h1>Seleciona un archivo:</h1><input required type="file"  name="archivo" class="file" value="Seleciona un Archivo">
<h1>Descripcion:</h1><input required type="text" class="descrip" name="descripcion"  maxlength="40"  placeholder="Maximo de 45 caracteres...">
<h1>Sistema Operativo:</h1>
<select name="system" class="sistema"> 

<option name="windows7">Windows 7</option>
<option name="windows8">Windows 8</option>
<option name="windows8.1">Windows 8.1</option>
<option name="windows10">Windows 10</option>
<option name="linux">Linux</option>
<option name="macos">Mac/Os</option>
<option name="ios">IOS</option>
<option name="android">Android</option>

</select>

<br>

<input type="submit" name="publicar" class="publicar" value="Publicar Archivo">

</center>

</form>
```

CODIGO DE EL ENVIO DE DATOS A LA BASE DE DATOS:

```html
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$fecha = date("d-m-y");
$tamaño = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$sistema = $_POST['system'];
$descarga = $_POST[''];



$sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (titulo, archivo, descripcion, tipo, fecha, tamaño, sistema, descarga)
 VALUES ('$titulo', '$archivo', '$descripcion', '$tipo', '$fecha', '$tamaño', '$sistema', '$descarga')";

$insertar = mysqli_query($enlace, $sql);

if(!$insertar){

echo "<h5><center>!ERROR¡ Al publicar tu archivo</h5></center>";


}else{

echo "<center><h6>Tu Archivo se subio con exito!!!</h6></center>";

}

 ?>
```

---

El codigo para enviar esta en la misma pagina , pero igual no me funciona, e igual que action, tampoco me funciona y no me funciona igual. El codigo de INSERT INTO si se ejecuta en sql de mysql. Pero cuando completo los campos y envio no funciona.

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Mientras espero el codigo como texto, preguntare... donde está el action de tu form ?

Comment: Un detalle adicional, el tag HTML [center](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) no está soportado por HTML 5

Comment: En primer lugar el código lo debes de poner como texto, por otro lado a tu formulario le falta el atributo "action" en el cual indicas el archivo al que enviaras los datos: <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post"> [En este enlace encontraras más información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: porfavor amigos

Comment: Te hemos dicho varias cosas....has intentado algo ??

Comment: No me funciona con ningun metodo...

Comment: Nose que hacer este problema lo tengo hace un mes

Comment: Soy principiante en php, pongo el codigo todo como me lo dice y no me funciona. Copie el codigo de otra computadora (Que si me funciona) y no pasa nada.